# Carta di Soggiorno di Familiare di un Cittadino dell'Unione

Tags: schengen

I have a *carta di soggiorno di familiare di un cittadino dell'unione.*  I am Pakistani. Can I visit Schengen countries without showing my Pakistani passport or without going to the Pakistan embassy?

Comment: All caps is difficult to read and makes it appear that you are shouting.  I have edited the question.

Comment: Of interest: *[Rights if we possess Carta di Soggiorno?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95904/)*, *[Travelling with a valid 'Carta di soggiorno'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82204/)* and possibly *[Can I travel to Schengen countries with only an Italian Carta di Identità?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95993)*

Answer (score 2):

> Can I visit Schengen countries without showing my Pakistani passport[?]

Probably not.  It depends on which countries you're going to.  In general, Schengen countries can require you to have a passport in addition to your residence card, and many of them do indeed have such a requirement.  You should take your passport with you.

> ... or without going to the Pakistan embassy?

Yes; there's no need for you to go to the Pakistan embassy unless you need to get a new passport.

Comment: i have my new passport and i want to visit France. so without go to Pakistan Embassy can i go to FRANCE?

Comment: @KhanKhanKhan Yes, you can go to France.  Take your passport.  Why would you think that you have to go to the Pakistani embassy?

Comment: some one say me that if you go schengen countries or other EU countries before out italy you must be go to embassy to tell them that i go to out or visit. its true?

Comment: @phoog are you able to update with some references?

Comment: @MarkMayo what references would I add?  ID requirements for foreigners vary from country to country, so listing each Schengen country's requirements is impractical.  As to the supposed requirement to notify the Pakistani embassy, there will be no page explaining that it does not exist, just as there is no source explaining that it is not necessary to notify the Pakistani embassy before changing your employer or brushing your teeth.

Comment: @phoog well, you mentioned in general, that Schengen countries can require a passport etc - a link to an example might help.  Not fussed with the final part, or brushing of teeth ;)